# Power BI: How to countrows by a category and use result to rank each category?

Tags: powerbi, dax, summarize

This should be simple, but I find it incredibly frustrating.  I have a table with information on Cases, with Date Initiated, Date to Pricing, and Partner columns. I want to count the cases by Partner that were initiated within a date range, and have a Date To Pricing entry.  Here's my code:

```
Rank Pard Cases Priced. = 
VAR Table0 = 
FILTER ( 'Cases',
    not ISBLANK( [Date To Pricing] )
    && [Date Initiated] >= date(2021,1,1)
    && [Date Initiated] <= DATE(2021,12,31)  )
VAR 
    Table1 =
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( 
            'Cases'[Partner],
            "Price_Pard", 
                countrows(FILTER ( 'Cases',
                    not ISBLANK( [Date To Pricing] )
                    && [Date Initiated] >= date(2021,1,1)
                    && [Date Initiated] <= DATE(2021,12,31) ) )  )      
VAR 
    Table2 =
        ADDCOLUMNS( Table1, "Rank", RANKX(Table1, [Price_Pard],, DESC, Skip))
        
RETURN 
    MINX(Table2, [Rank])
```

When I EVALUATE this code in DAX Studio, ending with RETURN Table2, I get exactly what I'm looking for, a table of the Partners, the counts, and the ranks.

I'm using this measure on a visual table that has the Partner name, so I expect it to give me a column with the expected ranks.  However, I get the dreaded message:

[image: Can't load data error message]

I really have no idea what that means.  Where does the "AddMissingItems" come from?  I've been getting it a lot lately, even with measures that are simpler than this one, and don't involve any summarizing.  I think the problem might be with having a FILTER inside SUMMARIZECOLUMNS apparently that's not well-supported.  I've been researching this for 2 hours, and haven't found a solution, or an alternative that works.  Most of what I read is confusing rather than helpful.

If I use the measure all by itself in a Card, with no Partner filter context, it works and gives me a value of 1, as expected (the min rank).

So my questions are:
(1) What does that error message mean?
(2) How can I get my code to work?
(3) If I need to restructure the query using SELECTCOLUMNS and grouping, please give me specifics.  I've tried a few variations on that, but without any luck.  In DAX Studio, the results are the same for every Partner: the total number of lines, and rank 1.

Comment: SUMMARIZECOLUMNS can't be utilized in a DAX measure. This syntax succeeds in a table expression but not when used in a measure. You need to write the measure differently to achieve your goal. You may want to share a sample data and desired output.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's the first explanation I've see that explains the problem with Summarizecolumns.  Try as I might, I can't get a functioning version of my measure. I'd appreciate it greatly if someone can show me how to do that.